# Uncaught (in promise): navigation stack needs at least one root page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, progressive-web-apps

I want to set the button back to my child's page, I am using the pop function but it is not working.

I am using this code

```
 import { IonicPage, NavController,} from 'ionic-angular';

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, ) {
    this.contactArray=JSON.stringify(this.navParams.get("contactArray")); 
    if(!this.contactArray || this.contactArray == ''){
       this.navCtrl.pop();
    }else{
      this.loadContactDetails();
    }    

  }
```

I am getting this

Error: Uncaught (in promise): navigation stack needs at least one root page
    at c (polyfills.js:3)

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Can you check if [this forum solution](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/navigation-stack-needs-at-least-one-root-page/90576/18) applies to you?

Comment: Yes.In one case refreshing of page.